# DataTables not initializing, using RequireJS/Backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, datatables, handlebars.js

I've worked with Require and DataTables before but this is my first time really setting things up. I've stripped away some of the sensitive files being called in the code below but I think this is everything you all would need to help out.

I have seen mixed messages on whether just the min JS path needs to be added or if you need both. Because there aren't errors present it seems like everything is bring properly called. In addition, I've heard mixed messages about needing a shim for DataTables. Does everything seem right? I have a standard table in a handlebars file that is populated with a json file. Let me know if you need those shown as well.

First section of code is from the require.config file, last chunk is from my view for the handlebars file.

```
requirejs.config({
  // baseUrl: "js",
  paths: {
    backbone: "bower_components/backbone/backbone",
    jquery: "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery",
    jqueryBridget: "bower_components/jquery-bridget/jquery.bridget",
    jqueryui: "bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui",    
    modernizr: "bower_components/modernizr/modernizr",
    datatables: "bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min"
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    jquery: {
      exports: "$"
    },
    modernizr: {
      exports: "Modernizr"
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
      exports: "Backbone"
    }

  }
});

define(["marionette", "hbs!apps/project/templates/components/project-funds/project-funds-performancetable", "datatables"],
  function (Marionette, projectFundsPerformanceTableTemplate, DataTables) {
    var ProjectFundsPerformanceTableView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      template: projectFundsPerformanceTableTemplate,
      initialize: function () {
        this.deferred = this.model.fetch({
          reset: true, 
          // dataType: "jsonp",
          success: (function () {
              // alert(' Service request success: ');              
          }), 
            error: (function (e) {
              // alert(' Service request failure: ' + e);
          }),
          complete: (function (e) {
              // alert(' Service request completed ' + e);               
          })
        });
        this.model.on("reset", this.render);
      },
      onShow: function(){
        $('#ce--funds--performanceTable').DataTable();
      }
    });
    return ProjectFundsPerformanceTableView;
  });
```

Comment: datatables requires jquery try ading a shim with depedencies

Comment: @NikosM. I tried adding datatables: ["jquery"] and datatables: {deps: ["jquery"]}. Neither worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are using recent versions of jQuery, Backbone and Underscore, they do not need shims.

jQuery has not needed a shim since some time before 1.9.

Check the annotated source of [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) and [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html). Search for "amd" in both sources and you'll see that they detect an AMD loader and call `define` when an AMD loader is present, so no shims.

Using `shim` where it is not needed *can* lead to undefined behavior and *can* explain the problem you are experiencing.

Oh, and DataTables does not need a shim either if you are using a relatively recent version. I use 1.10.2 without a shim.

Comment: Alright, I'll update the backbone and underscore stuff. Anything you can suggest on why DataTables isn't initializing on the table?